# Xamarin Android.dll (v9.0)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have updated my VS2017 and now xamarin showing me this warning:

> The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for App1.Android.dll (v9.0) is greater
>   than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v8.1). You need
>   to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.

It's just warning, but some piece of my code doesn't work after update. On other PC, which I haven't updated - code works fine. Can anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: start Android SDK Manager and install Android Pie (P/9) Platform tools.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you updated also the android sdk.
Make sure the Versions of your project match with the properties off App1.

Right-click on startup project / Properties -> Android Manifest

[image: Properties/Android Manifest]

Right-click on startup/reference project /Properties/Application
[image]